# Solr integration with multiple store multiple language e-commerce system

Tags: architecture, solr, e-commerce

this is an architecture related question and not specifically programming related issue.

We are working on a solr integration with our e-commerce shop. We're having a multiple store using the same system. The e-commerce system we're using offers multiple store setup that can be done with single language or different language for each store.

Basic integration is ready that works nicely since last year for single store. But as we now need to start another store, how should we proceed?

We can go for having different solr core for each store.

Or, we can either add store as a multi-valued field in solr and modify all queries we're doing with a filter for store id. This is simple, and may work fine for our current requirements.

However, suppose if we need to to use different language for newer store, this setup might not work correctly.. as I read somewhere that for different language we should use different core (per language). So the earlier multi-valued kind of integration actually not work when we have different language for that store.. and need a new solr core for each new store... or may be each new language.

One of the store has two languages planned.. so we have single store - multiple language scenario where single store- single core doesn't work.

My concerns are:
1. What performance impact it may have if I add a filter query for store while querying into the Solr. What could be the alternative?
2. Should I use different Solr core per store or different Solr core per language? Why?

I am open to ideas on what should we use. What could be the disadvantage of having solr core for each language? And if one store has multiple store, that can query into different solr core depending on the current language set by the visitor.

Please feel free to let us know if you have any other idea?

How does this kind of integration is handled by other e-commerce systems like Magento, Prestashop, etc?

Comment: I count 7 question marks in this single "question". This isn't so much a question as a request for free consulting. Your concerns aren't invalid, this is just the wrong forum for this question. Consider contracting a Solr expert to help you.

Comment: hey, thanks for your response. I somewhat agree with you as this is a wrong place for this question. However, we have figured out the best way on our own after looking at other stores and doing some testing with our own. So far its working great without any issue. Thanks for your response.

Comment: You have a lot of real world questions - I'm open to talk about that, since I've work hard with Solr and especially with it's integration to different e-commerce platforms